# Isomorphic semidirect products induce isomorphic kernels

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, semidirect-product

Let $\varphi_1:K\rightarrow\text{Aut}(H)$ and $\varphi_2:K\rightarrow\text{Aut}(H)$ be  two homomorphisms. Suppose that the semidirect products constructed by these homomorphisms are isomorphic by an isomorphism $\varphi$ such that $\varphi(H)=H$. Does $\ker\varphi_1\cong\ker\varphi_2$?. The result is true if $H$ is a non trivial p-group and $K$ is a non trivial q-group, where $p$ and $q$ are distinct prime numbers. However, this is not true in general, so are there additional conditions under which the statement is true?.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Can you include why you think this doesn't hold in general?  I think I have a proof for all semidirect products, but I'm worried I missed something.

Comment: @ Jacob Manaker. Thank you for your comment.  It is very common for $\ker\varphi_1=\ker\varphi_2=1$ amongst non-isomorphic semi-direct products.  But  you can put your proof  for discussion.

Comment: Writing it out in detail, I did miss something; sorry.

Comment: Captain Lama argues that if
 the kernels of homomorphisms $\varphi_i:K\rightarrow\operatorname{Aut}(H)$, i=1,2,
 are isomorphic,  then the semidirect products $H\rtimes_{\varphi_i}H$ are not necessarily isomorphic. @نورالدين سنانو,  how does this statement relate to your problem? Thank you.

Comment: @kabenyuk. I think you are right. So what do you think about the following example.Let $H$ be nonabelian of order $6$. Let $\varphi_1(h)=id_{H} $ and $\varphi_2(h)(g) = hgh^{-1}$. Then $H\rtimes _{\varphi_1 }H\cong H\rtimes _{\varphi_2}H$ but $\ker(\varphi_1) = H$ and $\ker(\varphi_2) = 1$.

Comment: You are right. @Derek Holt gave a similar example in the first comment to the question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3453460/requested-hint-for-if-ker-varphi-1-not-cong-ker-varphi-2-then-h-rtim?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have $\ker \varphi_1 \cong \ker \varphi_2$ whenever $|K|$ and $|H/Z(H)|$ are coprime.

To see that, note that $|H/Z(H)| = |{\rm Inn}(H)|$ so, if this condition is met, then  $\varphi_1(K) \cap {\rm Inn}(H) = 1$ and no element of $K$ can induce a nontrivial inner automorphism of $H$.

Then $C_{H \rtimes_{\phi_1} K}(H) = H \rtimes \ker \varphi_1$ and similarly $C_{H \rtimes_{\phi_2} K}(H) = H \rtimes \ker \varphi_2$, so
$$H \rtimes_{\phi_1} K \cong H \rtimes_{\phi_2} K \Rightarrow \ker \varphi_1 \cong \ker \varphi_2.$$

Comment: Thank you sir, I appreciate that.